# Error trying to split a Linestring in PostGis

Tags: postgis, postgresql, splitting

I'm trying to split a group of Linestrings when they cross a Polygon shape, I'm using the following query:

```sql
SELECT
  v.*,
  c.name,
  (st_dump(st_split(v.geom, c.geom))).geom AS geom
INTO table
FROM
  linestrings v,
  polygon c
```

I get the following error:

```
"Splitter line has linear intersection with input" 
SQL State : XX00
```

So far I've tried to check valid/invalid geometries, do a Dump first to the polygon shape and nothing changes.

To summarize, I need to Split the line when they pass trough the polygon so I get two lines, one with the information of the polygon and one without it.

EDIT: Sample data based on the comments

[image]

The polygons are the pink lines (no background but it's a polygon) and green lines are the linestrings (streets) I need to split when they pass through the polygon.

Indeed, some of the lines equal the polygon I'd like to split from, how can I handle this? Because using ST_DIfference would kill the lines (streets) I also need

Appreciatte the help

Comment: One (or more) of your *LineStrings* runs along (equals) the boundary of one (or more) of your *Polygons*; naturally, you cannot split a line with another one running on top of it. This is not trivial (especially if your data lacks a few preconditions), and likely needs a `UNION` of `ST_Intersection` and `ST_Difference` (which is also not trivial...). Can you share example data?

Comment: Edited the post, thanks

Comment: does converting polygons to lines help approach your goal?